# Yii 1.1.14 access control specify actions

Tags: php, yii, filter, action, access-control

I want to apply accessControl filter to all actions in a controller ***except two***,

so if i apply [-] as written in code, will that be okay.?

```
public function filters(){
    return array(
        'accessControl - actionId1, actionId2',
    );
}
```

Or there is some error in the code, and i do it in some other way?

Comment: Don't use Yii 1.1.14 because there is a security bug inside. http://www.yiiframework.com/news/78/yii-1-1-15-is-released-security-fix/ Update your Yii Framework to 1.1.15!

Comment: @lin I am not using CDetailView widget.. nor i plan to do so in near future, does it still makes my yii vulnerable to this security issue?

Comment: no. You'll be fine with that so. But you need to keep that in mind the hole time your software running on 1.1.14.

Answer (score 0):

This will work but you should use

```
array(
'allow',
'actions'=>array('actionId1', 'actionId2'),
'users'=>array('*'),
)
```

in the **acessRules()** For the actions for which you do not want any rule

**Note:-** `'users'=>array('*')` provides access to these actions to all the users

Comment: `public function filters(){
  return array(
            
'application.filters.EnsureLiveUser - index, login, logout, upload);
}`
I created a class and did this, should i write what u suggested in accessRules() method of controller or in filter() method @Let me see

Comment: accessRules() is specifically used by accessControl filter. thus any custom filter class will not use that method, i did as u suggested and came to this conclusion after a long debug session.
@let me see